# traceview command run issue

Tags: android, debugging

I am trying to use traceview to run some profiling against an Android application. I have wrapped the code that I want to trace with the following lines:

```
Debug.startMethodTracing("xxx"); 
// code 
Debug.stopMethodTracing();
```

It successfully generated a trace file, that I pulled from sdcard using the following command line:

```
$./traceview ~/code/packages/performance_trance.trace 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.Arrays.copyOf([II)[I
    at com.android.traceview.ProfileProvider.getColumnWidths(ProfileProvider.java:143)
    at com.android.traceview.ProfileView.<init>(ProfileView.java:85)
    at com.android.traceview.MainWindow.createContents(MainWindow.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
    at com.android.traceview.MainWindow.run(MainWindow.java:65)
    at com.android.traceview.MainWindow.main(MainWindow.java:269)
```

I cannot understand this error message and I didn't find anything useful on Google.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to open the file with your eclipse (with adt plugin)